# MySQL command to get only the latest data in Spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

The following shows one entity, where the same product (same pid) is given a rating by two different users (different uid). I want to get the latest data about average_stars (namely the second column data), which is 4.50. I used a MySQL command **findTopByProduct**, which shows me the older average_stars instead, namely 4.00. I tried **findBottomByProduct**, which turns out to be non-existent. I will really appreciate anyone who can help me with this simple question. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: So, you want the result be sorted by column "total_numbers_of_users_who“ and filtered by column „pid“?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: findTopByProductOrderByPruidDesc